# How can I ghostwrite a book?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to write a book without putting my name on it. Is this possible?

Comment: http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Book_and_Quill - without an author cited, hence, ghostwriting. I thought that was the correct word for this practice? I edited the body to hopefully make more sense.

Comment: Ghostwritting refers to an auther that writes a book but will not have their name associated with the book. So yeah, thats sort of applicable.   I would suggest looking into editing item values. Its a bit tricky as it involves fiddling with the world save. (I have only done it a few times back in the earlier days of minecraft. To allow cheats in a world created without them inabled.) You'll need to track down some program that will allow you to compile the world save into a manipulatable text file. Then save and boom. Its been too long for me to remember which programs I used. Sorry.

Comment: Also... I shouldnt have to say this, but. Make absolutely sure you have created back up copys of your world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When finished writing a book, click "Done" and leave it as a Book and Quill. You may want to rename it in an anvil to give it a title.

[image]

This allows anyone else who gets the book to edit or sign it themselves.

If you wish to avoid this, **and** you have access to the world file, you can press "Sign" on the book GUI and then locate and change the author name of the book with an NBT editor:

[image]